# Any ideas about how to style this DIV?

Tags: html, css

I have this , and i want to move the total reviews(The ones that show how many reviews are with how many stars) 
Here's how it looks https://i.gyazo.com/a766d0a8804da7ed34d4b295976414b5.png
The mark up is like

```
<div style="border-top: 1px solid #ddd; padding-top: 20px; vertical-align:top">                 
<div id="reviews-summary">                  
<p class="lead" style="margin-top: 0px;">{if $reviews}
<span id="product-stats">
<div class="ratings">
<div class="empty-stars"></div>
<div class="full-stars" style="width:{$review_stats.avg_rating*20}%">
<span class="total-reviews"></span></div></div>
</span>
</div>

<span class="average-rating">{$review_stats.avg_rating}</span>
<span class="total-reviews"> ({$review_stats.total} review{if $review_stats.total > 1}s{/if})</span>
```

I could've made first div inline block and give it a width of 50% but the line won't go across the whole div anymore. Any ideea is welcome.

Comment: Can you post the full code?

Comment: @abhiox well below is just javascript,i could post the css for those classes if ur interested but empty/full stars are just stars nothing else only colors and stuff defined

Comment: Please post the CSS too.

Comment: where do you want to move the total reviews?

Comment: @Paplusc like the element from it's left, up that div

Comment: Have you tried using `float:right or left` in your `css`?